# Loading the same native module into TWO node.js threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker

I have a native C++ module that is spun up by a worker thread from node.js, which works great.  From within that node module, I can call my native methods like "AddToLog()" and it works great.

I also need to service web requests, which is my dilemma.  So I used express and included a file to start it up on a worker thread.  That also works fine - both my native code and the express web server are working at the same time.

However, when I try to 'require' my native module in the file that starts the web server, I get an error that the native module could not be registered.

Have I hit a fundamental limitation where node.js cannot load the same native module on two different worker threads?  Or this is as simple as a syntax issue?

My hunch is that I can fix this by making the module context aware, but I'm too new to this to know for sure!

I need the express thread to be able to access the module in order to draw its content.  So one thread is running a lighting server that collects data and the other services web requests that describe the current state... if it worked!

```
// SCRIPT 1
'use strict'

const nightdriver = require('./build/Release/nightdriver.node')
const { Worker }  = require('worker_threads');

function startserver()
{
    nightdriver.addtolog("[index.js] Starting NightDriver Server");
    //nightdriver.startserver();
}

const worker = new Worker("./startweb.js");

nightdriver.addtolog("[index.js] Starting Web Server...");
startserver();

// SCRIPT 2
'use strict'
const nightdriver = require('./build/Release/nightdriver.node')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
 })

 var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
 })

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dave/OneDrive/Source/Node/nightdriver/startweb.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Worker.[kOnErrorMessage] (internal/worker.js:332:10)
    at Worker.[kOnMessage] (internal/worker.js:342:37)
    at MessagePort.Worker.(anonymous function).on (internal/worker.js:279:57)
    at MessagePort.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at MessagePort.onmessage (internal/worker.js:84:8)
```